# c++ classes not working for me

Tags: c++, class, variables, scope

I have written this program but it doesn't work. It gives an error  that `x` and `y` was not declared and expected primary expression before int on line `17`.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class shapes
{
    int width, height;
public:
    int getvalue();
    void decideshape(int l, int b);
};

main()
{
    cout<<"to find what type of shape you have input the measurements"<<endl;
    shapes toy;
    toy.getvalue();
    toy.decideshape();
}

int shapes::getvalue()
{
    int l, b;
    cout<<"length = ";
    cin>>l;
    cout<<"breath = ";
    cin>>b;
}

void shapes::decideshape(x, y)
{
    if(x==y)
        cout<<"This is square"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"This is rectangle"<<endl;
}
```

how should i return 2 values from function getvalue

Comment: Also you define a return type for `getvalue()` so you need to return an integer, even if it is `return 0;`

Answer (score 4):

1. Arguments are required to have types in C++. Write your definition of `shapes::decideshape` as

   ```
   void shapes::decideshape(int x, int y)
   ```
2. You don't return a value from `shapes::getvalue`.
3. You pass too few (actually none) parameters to `shapes::decideshape`. Two `int`s are expected to be supplied.
4. You need to tell the compiler what a function returns **explicitly**. Add the `int` return value to `main`.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked i called decideshapes inside getvalue.

Comment: how should i return 2 values from function getvalue

Comment: @Dementor Of the same type? What circumstances? If you have another question, ask another in a seperate thread. Also, first show **your** approach. We'll help you if it doesn't work.

Comment: same type, i want to return length and breath from getvalues() to main or directly to decideshape() function

Comment: @Dementor You could declare/define `void shapes::getvalue(int& length, int& breath)` and then modify the variables through the references passed. However, better would be to use seperate functions for each value.

Comment: why should i pass address to getvalue(). i didn't get you

Comment: @Dementor These are references, not addresses. Do some research on them.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the type of `x` and `y` in the parameter list:

```
void shapes::decideshape(int x, int y)
```